# What are the advantages of wrapping a react application using <ApolloProvider> as compared to make mutations and queries directly using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm new to `Apollo Client` React. I was reading the docs and i found this `<ApolloProvider>` wrapper which seems scary to me. My question is why do we need `<ApolloProvider>` if we can make queries directly and mutations using vanilla `js.`. I mean why don't we just make queries  for example like this:

```js
...
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:3001/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

...
  client
    .query({
      query: gql`
        {
          books {
            name
            id
            author {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    })
    .then((result) => console.log(result.data));
```

and then store the results in a state. **I'm not actually asking `Why?` per say.** I'm looking for the advantages of this approach of a wrapper `<ApolloProvider>` over making queries and store them in `redux-state`. Making mutations directly by calling `client.mutate(...)` without bothering using the `useQuery()` apollo hooks.